# First existing row from multiple queries

Tags: mysql, performance, union-all

In our application we try to find the best possible match for a given set of parameters. We have divided these rows into different quality groups that match on a subset of the total set of parameters. To match these different groups we have multiple select queries that we query subsequently if no result was found, we now decided to join them together using UNION ALL with a LIMIT 1. Which resulted in something like the following;

```
SET @size = 4, @price = 18, @category = 'NEW', @weight = 20, @origin = 'France';
(SELECT * FROM product_catalog WHERE quality = 'A1' AND size = @size AND price = @price AND category = @category AND weight = @weight AND origin = @origin LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM product_catalog WHERE quality = 'A2' AND size = @size AND price = @price AND category = @category AND origin = @origin LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM product_catalog WHERE quality = 'A3' AND price = @price AND category = @category AND weight = @weight AND origin = @origin LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM product_catalog WHERE quality = 'A4' AND price = @price AND category = @category AND origin = @origin LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
... SOME MORE SELECTS ...
LIMIT 1
```

Now the query does run as expected, it however performs way worse than our current solution. I think this has to do with the fact that MySQL may be performing the UNION statements first and then realizing it only needed to return the first one?

Do you have any suggestions that may help speed up the query? Do you think it is possible to rewrite the query to a stored procedure that will check each query for a result and return as soon as it finds one? Will this speed up the query?

Comment: MySQL will evaluate all parts. Some thoughts though: a) without an overall order by, your last limit can take *ANY* unspecified random row of any union, so it's not equivalent to trying the first query and only continuing with the next if you found nothing. b) If you add indexes for all combinations, this query should run in <0.2s. Not sure if it does that already and you just need it to be much faster as you run in 1000 times per minute, but otherwise you should check your indexes first. c) `or`, an `order by quality` and just one limit might be faster than `union`, depending on the indexes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was afraid of your point a), but I didn't know for sure if this was the case. Further the query does run under 0.2 seconds in fact even faster but as you have guessed I need to run this query millions of times in total. I did some rewriting and I now have a solution that incorporates the queries using some `ORDER BY` and `(size = @size OR size IS NULL)` magic.

Answer (score 1):

First, some of the issues...

- `UNION` always builds a tmp table.  (This inefficiency is eliminated, where practical, in MySQL 5.7.3 and MariaDB 10.1).
- The query is missing an `ORDER BY` at the end -- this *could* lead to getting the wrong answer.
- A second tmp table would be needed to do the outer `ORDER BY`.

Now some suggested improvements.  Without knowing more about the data, I have to say that these may or may not run faster.

Avoiding `*`:

Instead of doing `SELECT *`, just `SELECT id` and then `JOIN` back to the table to get the rest of the columns:

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM ( SELECT id ... UNION ALL ... LIMIT 1 ) AS a
    JOIN product_quality AS b  USING(id);
```

More indexes:

```
INDEX(quality, size, price)
INDEX(quality, price, category)
...
```

Do a single table scan; no index needed.  (This requires that `quality` values are ordered.):

```
SELECT * FROM ...
    WHERE ( quality = 'A1' AND size = @size AND price = @price ... )
       OR ( quality = 'A3' AND price = @price AND category = @category ... )
    ORDER BY quality
    LIMIT 1
```

(Normally, I recommend replacing `OR` by `UNION` for performance, but I think your use case works the other way.)

`CASE`:

Your first two selects could be combined:

```
SELECT MIN(IF(weight = @weight, 'A1', 'A2')) AS quality
    WHERE size = @size
      AND price = @price
      AND category = @category
      AND origin = @origin )
```

Comment: UNION ALL is also optimized to avoid a temp table where possible in MySQL 5.7.3. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50674

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I do actually use specific columns rather than using *, but for simplicity I omitted the columns maybe I should have mentioned that. Your OR query is close to what I am looking for, but I guess the DB will still check alle cases before returning the one with the highest quality, correct? Isn't there a way where, if the A1 quality matches, it immediately returns instead of considering the other cases?